# Webpart: Impersonation / RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: c#, moss

I am using MOSS 07 & VisualStudio 07 (c#) on a WindowsServer2003

My Problem is that I want to have access from one Sharepoint to another.
In SharePoint_1 is a SPList I want to read out from SharePoint_2.

The results of my research are IMPERSONATION and RUN_WITH_ELEVATED_PRIVILEGES.
With impersonation I can read out the html code of the SPSite I am connected with, but how can I get the List I want?
When I try to RunWithElevatedPrivileges I have to take a user form the site of SharePoint_1. But I cant get the User (even if I got his name) because of a FileNotFoundException.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

There is something I forgot to tell.
In the List are Attachments and I need access to them, too.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?
Hopefully its not very tricky, because I used Sharepoint 5 weeks ago the first time and dont so feel very familiar with it :)

Thanks

Comment: Is that two SPSites on the same server? Do you have a different admin user for each? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to specify a user when using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges. I think you will be ok if you use:

[url] = url to the other site collection

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => {
    using (var site = new SPSite("[url]")) {
        using (var web = site.OpenWeb()) {
            // Access list here
        }
        site.RootWeb.Dispose();
    }
});
```